# Avoid pipeline duplication in github on Push and open merge request

Tags: github, github-actions

**Feature1** branch is being merged to **epic1** branch => the pull request is open with following

```
on: 
  push:
  pull_request:
```

Push to Feature1 branch will trigger 2 pipelines

- 1 for push
- 2 for pull_request

How to avoid running push pipeline on a commit if there is an open pull request?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an exact method yet but there are always some tricks.

**Possible tricks:**

1. Close the pull request and trigger the workflow only on push (I think this is not appropriate for you)
2. Keep the pull request opened, trigger your workflow only on **pull_request**, like

   `on: [pull_request]`

event, whenever you push in this case,    workflow will be triggered only once (since pull request is opened).

3. Somethings are guided by github also, you can use the [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#example-excluding-branches-and-tags), where you can disable your wanted branch for push or pull request event.

Comment: ideally, you want to run build and test on personal feature branches to ensure there are no issues so running pipeline only on pull_request will not provide continuous feedback